How to return a pointer containing data from Swift to C
I am writing a program in Swift that does computation on the GPU. Below is the code that generates a random matrix using Metal performance shaders:
func randomMatrix(
    rows: Int, 
    columns: Int,
    result: UnsafeMutableRawPointer
){
    autoreleasepool{

        let bufferSize = rows * columns * MemoryLayout<Float32>.size
        let resultBuffer = device!.makeBuffer(
            length: bufferSize,
            options: .storageModeShared
        )

        let matrixDescriptor = MPSMatrixDescriptor(
            rows: rows, 
            columns: columns, 
            rowBytes: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * columns, 
            dataType: .float32)
        
        let outputMatrix = MPSMatrix(
            buffer: resultBuffer!, 
            descriptor: matrixDescriptor
        )
        
        let randomMatrixDescriptor = 
            MPSMatrixRandomDistributionDescriptor.uniformDistributionDescriptor(
                withMinimum: -1.0, 
                maximum: 1.0
            )
        let matrixRandomKernel = MPSMatrixRandomMTGP32(
            device: device!, 
            destinationDataType: .float32, 
            seed: 43, 
            distributionDescriptor: randomMatrixDescriptor
        )

        let commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()

        matrixRandomKernel.encode(commandBuffer: commandBuffer!, destinationMatrix: outputMatrix)

        commandBuffer?.commit() // Push command to the buffer
        commandBuffer?.waitUntilCompleted()
        
        memcpy(result, resultBuffer!.contents(), MemoryLayout<Float32>.size * rows * columns)
    }
    
}

This code works well, but when generating large matrices (say of dimensions 100,000 x 100,000 or more), memcpy creates a bottleneck. Therefore, I am looking for a way to eliminate the memcpy.
The signature of the function on C side is
void metalRandomMatrix(float minimum, float maximum, int rows, int columns, float *result);

I have tried to create the buffer on Swift side with the argument bytesNoCopy, but that crashes the application when run on C side. Alternatively, I have tried the following:
// method 1 --- returns garbage values
result.pointee = resultBuffer!.contents()

// method 2 --- works but is similar to memcpy, so defeats the purpose
let resultPointer = resultBuffer!.contents().assumingMemoryBound(to: Float32.self)
result.update(from: resultPointer, count: rows * columns)

// method 3 --- returns garbage values       
result.pointee = resultBuffer!.contents().assumingMemoryBound(to: Float32.self)
result.initialize(to: resultPointer)

Could anyone help me with this? Thank you.

What do you mean by "crashes the application".

Why not just take .contents() of the buffer and return that and keep the buffer alive while you use that.

How do I keep the buffer alive? For some more context the Swift is compiled as a dynamic library and it is called from application written in C. By "crashes the application", I mean, it just abruptly quits. I tried adding some log lines, and  found it closes just before creating the output matrix.

How can you imaging processing a 10 billion float matrix ? Way beyond memory of device.

Crashes generate crash logs, it would be helpful to know what's in them. It doesn't matter how it's compiled and how it's called.

@Spo1ler I have uploaded the crash log here: http://0x0.st/X99N.txt
